# In SSRS, is it possible to change the Visibility property of a textbox depending on the toggle status of a group?

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have a question regarding report creation in SSRS 2008 R2. After my report runs, my information is formatted as follows:
(+/- symbols denote toggle states)

```
    Store

       Animal     Count     Total Cost

    -Pet Store A    30       $390.00

       +Dog         15       $200.00

       +Cat         10       $150.00

       +Fish         5        $40.00

           Total:   30       $390.00
```

As you can see, I have the total in the top of the list and the bottom. The *Store* group can be toggled to hide all of the subgroups and the total in teh bottem.I would like it so that the total count and cost on top are hidden when expanded like this, yet be visible when collapsed.
I have tried many expressions, but cannot seem to access the visibility property of the group. I was wondering if there is a way to access group properties so I can create an expression in the visibility group. I have tried changing the visibility to those text boxes to false and set the toggle to the textbox that "Pet Store A" is in, but that will hide the whole row group, which is not what I desire. 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/42a99ccc-e92f-4375-a21b-02e1909146ec

No, you can't get at the collapsed property of a group. [The link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1329/drill-down-techniques-in-ssrs-with-the-visibility-property/) provided in that discussion thread provides some potential workarounds.